# Export all translatable string/content/fields/interface to a csv file or alternative

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I know there is node contents and fields that need translation, interface element translations, views title/footer translations etc

Is there an export for all these that can ideally later be imported or at least an easy workflow for a translator ?

Comment: For interface translation: We use [Potx](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) [(D8 version)](https://github.com/kgaut/drupal-potx)  to generate POT files, which can be translated and imported again.